# Int vs Float: Counter

Tags: c, comparison, byte, bit-manipulation, duplication

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    int ch1, ch2;
    clock_t elapsed;
    char fname1[40], fname2[40];

    printf("Enter name of first file:");
    fgets(fname1, 40, stdin);
    while ( fname1[strlen(fname1) - 1] == '\n')
    {
        fname1[strlen(fname1) -1] = '\0';
    }

    printf("Enter name of second file:");
    fgets(fname2, 40, stdin);
    while ( fname2[strlen(fname2) - 1] == '\n')
    {
        fname2[strlen(fname2) -1] = '\0';
    }

    fp1 = fopen(fname1, "r");
    if ( fp1 == NULL )
    {
        printf("Cannot open %s for reading\n", fname1 );
        exit(1);
    }

    fp2 = fopen( fname2,  "r");
    if (fp2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open %s for reading\n", fname2);
        exit(1);
    }

    elapsed = clock(); // get starting time

    ch1  =  getc(fp1); // read a value from each file
    ch2  =  getc(fp2);

    float counter = 0.0;
    float total = 0.0;

    while(1) // keep reading while values are equal or not equal; only end if it reaches the end of one of the files
    {
        ch1 = getc(fp1);
        ch2 = getc(fp2);

    //printf("%d, %d\n", ch1, ch2);// for debugging purposes

    if((ch1 ^ ch2) == 0)
    {
       counter++;
    }

    total++;

        if ( ( ch1 == EOF) || ( ch2 == EOF)) // if either file reaches the end, then its over!
        {
            break; // if either value is EOF
        }
    }

    fclose (fp1); // close files
    fclose (fp2);

    float percent = (counter / (total)) * 100.0;

    printf("Counter: %.2f Total: %.2f\n", counter, (total));
    printf("Percentage: %.2f%\n", percent);

    elapsed = clock() - elapsed; // elapsed time
    printf("That took %.4f seconds.\n", (float)elapsed/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to compare two .nc files that are about 1.4 GBs and these are my results:

```
$ gcc check2.c -w
$ ./a.out
Enter name of first file:air.197901.nc
Enter name of second file:air.197902.nc
Counter: 16777216.00 Total: 16777216.00
Percentage: 100.00%
That took 15.6500 seconds.
```

No way they are 100% identical lol, any ideas on why it seems to stop at the 16777216th byte?

The counter should be 1,256,756,880 bytes

1.3 GB (1,256,756,880 bytes)

I downloaded this climate data set here:

ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Datasets/NARR/pressure/

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: In fact, `counter` and `total` are float...with about 7 digit precision. I guess that it tries to compute 16777216+1 and found 16777216. Could you try to use `double` ? Moreover, two identical file except for the first byte will be found identical by your program. It should be what @McLovin meant...

Comment: you don't test the first byte atm. Better use `fpos_t` (if it is an unsigned integer type) or `unsigned long long` for size...

Comment: What @McLovin wants to say with this is that you are using a `float` for the counter. This has a significand of 2^24, i.e. that is the max precision of a `float`. Why are you not using an integral type for such large files (or for counters in general), e.g. a `uint32_t`? In other words: `float` is too limited and the wrong type to use for such a counter.

Comment: Displaying `total` and `counter` to two decimal places hardly makes any sense either.

Comment: You should probably perform the EOF check *before* attempting to compare the characters - though it will not have any affect on the results to two decimal places with such a large file.

Comment: The title says the code crashes. Where does it crash?

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't just break out as soon as one byte doesn't match? At that point you know the files are not equal and there is no need to keep checking them unless you are really interested in that percentage. If you are interested in the percentage you might think about including the bytes that were leftover from one file in the total. If you are not, you can just skip the equality check all together if the files are not the same size, because you know they won't match.

Comment: @Apriori Yes I am interested in the percentage, I would like to see the performance on this byte-by-byte comparison because it is very costly in terms of I/O

Comment: @Apriori Also, I am not interested in the total bytes leftover because I would just like to compare how many duplicate bytes are within the files. So, as soon as one file reaches the end, it will stop

Comment: And you are correct, it doesn't crash. I will change the title. I thought it did because initially I thought it didn't read through the whole file based on the percentage

Comment: @humblebeast: But you display the identical bytes as a percentage of the total bytes. I would think of bytes the larger file has that the smaller file does not as bytes that are not equal. It's also worth noting that with this logic you could have a two files that are 100% equal, but the second file is much larger than the first. This seem wrong to me. Or two files that are 50% equal, the first file being two bytes total with one byte equal, and the second file being several MB. You will also get a division by zero if one of the files is zero size.

Comment: @humblebeast: That's just my personal opinion of what makes sense and is intuitive though. Of course feel free to do what is right for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `float` data type is only precise to 6 significant figures and is inappropriate for `counter` and `total`.  Any floating point type would be inappropriate in any case. Ther are a number of issues with this, not least that `++` for example is an *integer operator*, the implicit conversion from float to int, increment, then back to float will fail for integer values with greater than 6 digits.

I assume you chose such a type because it has greater *range* that *unsigned int* perhaps?  I suggest that you use `unsigned long long` for these variables.

```
unsigned long long counter = 0;
unsigned long long total = 0;

...

float percent = (float)counter / (float)total * 100.0f ;
```

Comment: Agreed, it's really bad to use float/double for a counter such as this. As far as the percentage computation, better yet: use a fixed point computation for the percentage. `unsigned long long percent =  (100 * counter) / total;` or for rounding `unsigned long long percent =  (1000 * counter) / total; percent = percent / 10 + (percent % 10 >= 5);` it can easily be adapted for more decimal places. This saves a float to int conversion.

Comment: I considered advising a fixed point solution, but given that the output is displayed to two decimal places, using fp is the simple solution and on a target with floating-point is inexpensive.

Answer (score 0):

Use `int` type for `counter` and `total` variables

Comment: Do you have any DVD images or other big files (>2GB) stored on your PC? `int` won't cut it on a modern desktop...

Comment: I would recommend a fixed size type, like `uint32_t`, or for file sizes, `uint64_t`. One can never know if `int` is "big" enough.

Comment: For the file size in this example, `int` would work, but for >2Gb up to 4Gb `unsigned int`, and >4Gb, `long long` or `unsigned long long` are required.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis : good advice, but given the file size, it would hardly be an application for a 16 bit system perhaps?

Comment: @Clifford: you are probably right, but even if `int` is 32 bit, it would not cut it with files > 2GB.

Comment: @clifford: yes, you did, sorry.